# Minecraft horse breeding trouble

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have a problem with horse breeding in Minecraft on the Xbox One.

I have tried carrots and apples (golden of course) and the horses enter love mode, but there is no baby that comes out afterwards.

Comment: You have had a problem, so it must be fixed already.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears that the horses aren't tamed. Tame the horses first before using either golden apples or golden carrots.

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to feed BOTH of the horses
2. Both of them have to be tamed
3. You are breeding them too often (10 minute cooldown)